# Как в Vaadin сделать отношение master detail для двух таблиц или ComboBox

Tags: java, vaadin

Хочу сделать два связанных ComboBox. В одном скажем будут страны, в другом города. При переключении в первом, во втором остаются только значения нужной страны. Подскажите в каком направлении копать.

Comment: Какую версию Vaadin вы используете?

Comment: Последняя версия 7.6